# Is payload sent with HTTP POST that contains basic authentication?

Tags: rest, authentication, post, https

I have a client that is POSTing an XML document to a server that requires basic authentication. Are the payload and basic authentication header included in the same request or does the authentication occur before the payload is sent? I'm trying to send sensitive information to the server? Is it possible that sensitive information could still be accessed by the server even though the authentication failed?

Answer (score 0):

The request headers (which includes the [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header used by [basic authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2)) and the request message body (which is where your XML document would be copied) are conceptually part of the same message.

That message might be spread over multiple packets.

The request body will be sent separately from the body in some circumstances (for instance, in conjunction with the use of the [Expect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) header.

The authorization header describes the client, not the server - if you send unencrypted data to the server, of course it can read it.

The usual answer is to encrypt the entire http request, so that it can only be read by a process that can access the other half of the encryption secret.  In the most common use case, we use HTTPS to ensure that the request can only be read by a machine that can access the server's secret; client authorization still happens via the headers.

There are alternatives where the client proves its identify by using a specific secret in the encryption of the message (the server knows that the client is genuine by the fact that the correct matching piece successfully decrypted the message).